# Postman Embedded Environment Variables Not Being Evaluated

Tags: environment-variables, postman

I am using Postman v6.1.4. I am using environment variables heavily. But it appears that `pm.environment.get()` is not evaluating embedded variables.

I have the following env vars defined in the environment:

```
addFavDest1:{"ownerId":"{{addFavDest1_ownerId}}","url":"{{addFavDest1_url}}",...}
...
addFavDestArray1:[{{addFavDest1}},{{addFavDest2}},{{addFavDest3}}]
```

The request body of my API contains:

```
{{addFavDestArray1}}
```

The request is sent successfully, with the data I expect, evaluating all of the embedded variables in my environment.

However, when I try to access that env var in my test script, the embedded variables are not being evaluated. For instance, the following:

```
var addFavDestArray1 = pm.environment.get('addFavDestArray1')
```

Returns `[{{addFavDest1}},{{addFavDest2}},{{addFavDest3}}]`, with the variables not evaluated.

Is there some way to have the embedded variables evaluated in the environment?

Comment: This is a known issue. You have to live with it. `get()` gets string from environment as is. it doesn't evaluate anything.

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to handle this situation, I created the following common function that I call from all my tests instead of `pm.environment.get('var1')` or `environment['var1]` or `environment.var1`.

```
/* funcGetAndEvalEnvVar */
var funcGetAndEvalEnvVar = (varName) => {
  const EMBEDDED_VAR_REGEX = new RegExp(`{{\\w+}}`, 'g');
  var varValue = environment[varName];
  var evalVarValue = varValue;
  var reMatch;
  while (reMatch = EMBEDDED_VAR_REGEX.exec(varValue)) {
    var embeddedVar = reMatch[0];
    var embeddedVarName = embeddedVar.slice(2, -2);
    if (environment.hasOwnProperty(embeddedVarName)) {
      var embeddedVarValue = funcGetAndEvalEnvVar(embeddedVarName);
      evalVarValue = evalVarValue.replace(new RegExp(embeddedVar, 'g'), embeddedVarValue);
    }
  }
  return evalVarValue;
};
```